# Figure what fields `save()` acted on if any (detecting changes)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

Doing `->save()` and `->update()` only updates when changes made, I think, is this true?

Here's the relevant part of code in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model@performUpdate`:

```
protected function performUpdate(Builder $query, array $options = [])
{
    $dirty = $this->getDirty();

    if (count($dirty) > 0)
    {
        // runs update query
    }

    return true;
}
```

I typically update like this:

```
public function update(Requests\UpdatePetRequest $request, Pet $pet)
{
    $pet->update($request->all());
    return $pet;
}
```

I want to figure from `->save` and from `->update` if what field names were updated? Along with what was the old value and the new value.

I currently manually do this like this:

```
public function update(Requests\UpdatePetRequest $request, Pet $pet)
{
    $changes = [];
    if ($request->exists('name') && $request->name != $pet->name) {
        $changes['name'] = array([
            'old' => $pet->name,
            'new' => $request->name
        ]);
    }
    if ($request->exists('avatar') && $request->avatar != $pet->avatar) {
        $changes['avatar'] = array([
            'old' => $pet->avatar,
            'new' => $request->avatar
        ]);
    }

    if (!count($changes)) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>'No properties changed'], 422);
    }

    $pet->update($request->all());

    $body = json_encode($changes);

    $message = new Message(['body' => $body, 'kind' => 'PET_UPDATE']);
}
```

Is there an automated way to do this?

Comment: Where you want to detect it? You already have this data. `$product->price` is an old value and `$newPrice` is a new value.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I added how I currently manually do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with `update()`, but you can use `getDirty()` before `save()`:

```
$model = Model::find($id);
$model->fill($request->all());
$cahnges = $model->getDirty();
$model->save();
```

`getDirty()` will return you an array with changed columns only, for example:

```
['name' => 'New Name', 'address' => 'New Street, 12']
```

Comment: Wow ultra ultra cool, thank you sir so much! You are always so helpful! And soooo fast!!! It's like a live teacher!!

Comment: Is it possible to get the pre-changed values? when I try to make an object of new/old values its getting the new for both: https://gist.github.com/blagoh/ba12c27c35b9ad5371d47c9fcb7655d7

Comment: @Blagoh just save original model before using the `fill()`, for example `$petOld = $pet->toArray()`

Comment: Ack that is sooo cool I came across all of these in the laracasts I just fail to recall them. I think as I use them I'll get the memory, thank you again sooo much!